# docker service verify: Detected task failure

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, containers, docker-swarm

I want to create a service in docker swarm using the following command:

```
> "docker service create --name  jenkinsstack --network devops-net \
> --replicas 1 --publish 8080:8080 jenkins/jenkins \
> --mount type=bind,src=jenkins-volume,dst=/var/jenkins_home"
```

But I'm getting a failure when I try to create it. However when I remove the "--mount" part, everything worksfine. I can't figure out what the problem is.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

- The image needs to be at the end of the command.
- If you use a bind mount you need to specify a host-path not a volume.

In your case it should look more like this:

```
docker service create --name  jenkinsstack --network devops-net --replicas 1 --publish 8080:8080 --mount type=bind,src=some-host-path,dst=/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins
```

[reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/services/)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I knew I was missing something trivial.